# ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.EmailResult - inline image not in email, how to see html body of resulting email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, actionmailer.net

MVC 4, c#.net
sending emails using ActionMailer.Net.Mvc.EmailResult
using smtp server

using:
**_email_layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img alt="header.png" src="cid:header.png" />
    <div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**in MailController.cs**

```
ActionMailer.Net.Attachments.Inline.Add("header.png",  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/pic.png")));

ActionMAiler.Net.Mvc.EmailResult v = Email("myemailview", modelforview);
```

**Sending email with:**

```
myEmail.DeliverAsync();
```

If sent to our company emails - image is shown in the email as expected.

If sent to gmail.com - inline pic.png is not in email. 
Instead there is kind-of place holder with "header.png" next to it and garbage text at the end of email.

1. Is it possible to see how to see html body of resulting email ?
   Where is it in EmailResult object ?
2. Any ideas why inline image does not go through to outside emails?

Many thanks

Comment: You can check the html at mail client like outlook client or gmail (email -> show original).

Comment: Thank you, I compared original-email-with-image-issue with original-old-email-with-good-image and I can see that difference is that in old-email-with-good-image  for the image  "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"   and in the email-with-image-issue  "Content-Type: text/plain". But no clue why it's happening. . .